# How to play midi music in VirtualBox Windows 98?

Tags: audio, virtual-machine, midi, windows-98

I'd build a Windows 98 VM in my Mac with VirtualBox to run some old games, like "Z". It is running, but without the great soundtrack. When testing, I realize that the soundtrack is in midi files, and not even Media Player is playing any midi. It opens the file, knows time etc. (recognize the file) but no sound is played.

There is a Sound Blaster Midi Sinth installed, the problem might be the VM itself that don't emulate the full Sound Blaster 16 card. I'm thinking about some alternatives: to change the VM sound card (not a clue of how to do it), or to install a driver that synthesizes the midi in wave to use the wave port that is working, but didn't find one.

Also couldn't get in the Virtual Box forum, I'd make an Oracle profile, but didn't work. So  here I am… any ideas?

Comment: I'm actually really curious to know this too...but it is off topic for SO. Try asking on [su].

Comment: MIDI is not emulated by any VM I know. Your best bet would be to use USB passthrough with a hardware MIDI synthesizer.

Comment: I'm not the first asking about VM… USB is interesting, but never work well with win98, maybe I'll try for fun. Thanks!

Comment: I post the same at SuperUser: http://superuser.com/questions/851131/how-to-play-midi-music-in-virtualbox-windows-98 Maybe this topic should be closed, your call!

Comment: As you can see I **got it to work nicely with a standard Virtual Box WinXP VM**: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30582733/1915920

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been cross-posted on a better suited Stack Exchange site.For more information, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). http://superuser.com/questions/851131/how-to-play-midi-music-in-virtualbox-windows-98

Comment: I agree. I don't remember why I did post here, but it seams a post that caught some attention, I hope will continue at the new forum.

Answer (score 2):

(Although I did not try with *Z* or another game I tried with other/similar MIDI software...)

### *B)*-setup-based (WinXP)

It works great with my *B)* setup (see below) based on a WinXP VM and the separately to be installed *ICH AC97* Audio driver:

1. setup **WinXP VM**

   - set **audio hardware emulation to *ICH AC97***
2. **everything should work fine** then without distortions or hickups
3. maybe choose ***Microsoft GS Wavetable*** over *Microsoft MIDI mapper* since the **sounds are much nicer then**

(the latest [*Realtek Intel HD* Audio Driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/18627/Audio-Realtek-High-Definition-Audio-Driver) for *WinXP* did not work for me - installed ok, restarted but was not found nor can be manually assigned)

### *A)*-setup-based (Win7)

And then it **works only basically with my *A)* setup** (see below) based on a Win7 VM and

- the ***Intel HD Audio* driver (default)**
- some **MIDI file played in *Windows Media Player***

but:

- playing a MIDI file in *Windows Media Player* is fine
- playing the MIDI file in my music software *Band-in-a-box 12* over *Microsoft MIDI mapper* or *Microsoft GS Wavetable* is crappy with delays, jumps and distortions

It also seems to work with the [*AC97* driver on *Win95* and *Win98*](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=27688#p303892)

(Trying with some MIDI-based music program I first thought it did not work and tried with all the available *AC97*, *Soundblaster 16*, *Intel HD Audio* drivers and did not see some MIDI device in the device manager.
But it seems MIDI support is not mapped to a device and the problems are related to the software I tried it with.)

### my setups

- *Band-ina-box 12* as the app to test it

A)

- no special XP *exe* emulation setup done
- ***Win7 32bit* guest**
- *Win8.1 64bit* host
- ***Virtual Box 4.3.28*** (latest, 2015-06-01)

B)

- tried some XP *exe* emulation variants which did not help with the distortions and hickups
- *WinXP guest*
- *Win8.1 64bit* host
- ***Virtual Box 4.3.28*** (latest, 2015-06-01)

Comment: The only available card for me was sb16, now these two other are there, maybe after some upgrade… I'll have to find drivers for these cards for windows 98 (win95 won't work). I don't remember this cars back at that time, not sure if will be useful if apps for win98 does not support it, but it worth the try. Thanks!

Comment: I also tried my external USB sound device *TonePort UX1* (much more than you would need, but what I had available) under the above A)-setup, but could not get it to work with latest Win7 drivers (they installed and I can see them, but I can't hear anything and the system seems to hang trying to output some sounds). It may be a VM-unrelated problem though, but the suggestion to **use an external USB soundcard** is actually a nice idea.

Comment: Thanks. Very interesting. Sadly the AC97 installation bombed out with a 5009 in the Win98SE VM. Hopefully further information will come available post-forums at Creative.

Answer (score 1):

The standard MIDI port is 440, make sure your software is configured correctly to use the card (though judging by your level of knowledge in asking I'd imagine you've done this).

While this isn't specifically an answer about making VirtualBox do what you want, I'd recommend DOSBox when doing DOS or Win3x gaming over a regular virtual machine for performance and emulation accuracy.

You can get any DOS-based Windows (including 95) running on DOSBox or at least one of the patched builds of it (I recommend Taewoong's build at http://ykhwong.x-y.net/ as it is the most feature-complete). You could probably make 98, 98SE, and ME run on DOSBox too, but anything that won't run on 95 can probably be made to run on a modern version of Windows with less trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was taking the opportunity to learn more about VB emulating, exploring the limits. "Z" is troublemaker! Fortunately they port it to recent OSX, so I'm playing it natively! DOSBox also got it limits, it does not fully run Z or Z95 due to sound problems. This kind of game runs very near the hardware using DOS4GW etc.